# How can I add a character after each word in an array except the last one in a v-for loop in a vuejs application ? Separating words with a semicolon

Tags: vuejs2

I would like to separate some words with a semicolon. If I do it like this

```
<span v-for="(item, itemIndex) in arrayOfStrings"
     :key="itemIndex"
     v-html="item + ';'" />
```

the last word will also have a semicolon. How can I avoid the semicolon after the last word ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the join method

```
<span v-else>{{ arrayOfStrings.join("; ") }}</span>
```